# Is it possible to comment out blocks of code that contain comments in css?

Tags: css, comments

If I have some css

```
/* Labeled Section 1 */
.thing1 {}
.thing2 {}

/* Labeled Section 2 */
.thingA {}
.thingB {}
```

Is it possible to comment both sections out simultaneously?  Is there any form of super or sub comment which can be used to make commenting blocks of css which contain comments themselves easier?

EDIT: for those who've never done this before, adding comments around the whole thing doesn't work.

```
/*  START BIG COMMENT
/* Labeled Section 1  BIG COMMENT ACTUALLY ENDS HERE*/
.thing1 {}
.thing2 {}

/* Labeled Section 2 */
.thingA {}
.thingB {}
END BIG COMMENT */
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking....just open the comment `/*` where you want and the close it when you are finished `*/`  Everything in between is commented out,

Comment: Not if it runs into a `*/` before the one I want it to

Comment: There is no way, there arent a way to escape a `*/` on html. The first expression it finds it ends the comment. Is not like `{}` who is a hierarchy. If is something visual use the `*|` where u want to mark as end of comment but continue on comment mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most languages it is not possible to nest comments - this is also valid for CSS.

What you could do is only the following:

```
/* Labeled Section 1 */
/*
.thing1 {}
.thing2 {}
*/

/* Labeled Section 2 */
/*
.thingA {}
.thingB {}
*/
```

Or if you only want to have one comment block:

```
/*
/* Labeled Section 1 * /
.thing1 {}
.thing2 {}

/* Labeled Section 2 * /
.thingA {}
.thingB {}
*/
```

So it's important to add a space between all included comments `*` and `/`.

Which requires that you remove this extra space when removing the outer comment.

Comment:  Very cool trick!  Now only someone needs to integrate this idea into an IDE ("I" as in "integrated" — pun intended). So that when you comment a long multi line text all the inner comments get their space inserted to be invalidated as comment markup. And once you outcomment that long section, removes the space from the inner comment markers again, to make them "hot" again. Does anyone know IDEs which do that? Or a setting/plugin for VS Code?